# Auto logout on Cookie expire react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a `privateroute.js` file that checks permissions and token status every time a route is requested which is working fine. But the problem is even if the cookie expires it doesn't log out until I refresh the page.

**e.g** if I navigate from `localhost:3000` to `localhost:3000/dashboard/analytics` even if there is no cookie in memory it will allow me, but the moment I refresh the page it will take me back to the `login` page.

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

const cookies = new Cookies();
const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(null);
const navigate = useNavigate();
const user = cookies.get("authToken");
const _id=cookies.get("xyz");
useEffect(async() => {
let as=null;
const cookies = new Cookies();


if (user) {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Authorization':`Bearer ${user}`,
        },
    };
    try{
      const {data}=await axios.post(
        `/api/auth/Veri`,
      {
        _id
      },
      config
      );
      
      if(data.email){
        setAuthenticated(true);
      }
      else{
         
         navigate("authentication/card/login");
      }
    }
    catch(error){
      
      ast=false;
      
      navigate("authentication/card/login");
    }
}
else {
  ast=false;
  setAuthenticated(false);
  navigate("authentication/card/login");
}
 }
  , []);

 useEffect(()=>{
if(authenticated==false){
  navigate("authentication/card/login");
}
}, []);

return (
authenticated ? <Outlet/> : null
)
 }
   export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**Layout.js (Routing file)**

```
  <Route element={<PrivateRoutes/>}>
  <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
  {/*Dashboard*/}
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="dashboard/analytics" element={<Analytics />} />
  <Route path="dashboard/crm" element={<Crm />} />
  <Route path="dashboard/saas" element={<Saas />} />
  <Route path="dashboard/e-commerce" element={<Ecommerce />} />
 
  </Route>
  </Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the dependency array in useEffect

```js
useEffect(()=>{
if(authenticated==false){
  navigate("authentication/card/login");
}
}, [user]); <-- you can put suitable dependency that you think it is useful....
```